# Node: Not closing a redis client

Tags: database, node.js, redis, production-environment

I wanted to ask this questions since our application is really close to **production stage** and we do not want to mess any data.

I'm using **Redis** as the data layer between **Node** and **DB**, and I am doing operations that involves multiple data insertions to different tables. An example;

```
redisClientForStudent.select(1);
redisClientForTeacher.select(2)

redisClientForStudent.get('1', function(err, studentResult) {
  if(err) {
    //ERROR
  }
  else if(studentResult != null) {
    redisClientForTeacher.set('2', '{name:Jane}', function(err) {
      //SOME LOGIC
    });
  }
  else {
    //DATA NOT FOUND
  }
});
```

I wanted to point out that the code above is **not the actual code**. The reason why I am going to use multiple clients is because when I tried to the insert the multiple datas to multiple tables it gets mixed up. I am going to try this method, however my concerns are do I have to close each redis client in case of an error? Another question is, if using multiple clients does not prevent the data getting mixed, what additional precautions could be applied?

Comment: What do you mean on "when I tried to the insert the multiple datas to multiple tables it gets mixed up" ?

Comment: In case of an error you can use the event https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#end and when a client emits it, the another client can be closed, save the data or anything.